# Pausing the video for 15 seconds

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-editing, ffmpeg-filters

I have a video which is 40 seconds long, I want to make it 55 seconds long, I wanted that the video's first frame along with it's audio freezes (frame freezes) for the first 15 seconds and after the countdown of 15 seconds it starts running so that I can get the video 55 seconds long, is it possible ? I tried a trick but it didn't work, I will share it with you. I took a screen shot of the first frame of the video, saved it in 1.jpg, then I ran the following command.

> ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 15 -i 1.jpg  -c:v libx264 -vf
> 'scale=-2:min(1080,trunc(ih/2)*2)' -r 30 1.mp4

Afterwards I tried this video combine with the original video so that this 1.mp4 will run for 15 seconds with the first frame and then after 15 seconds the original video will start running, it works but in the process the seconds/original video louses its sound, the command which I used it following.

> ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy out.mp4

list.txt has the names of the videos.

Can someone help me in achieving this ?

Comment: if use tpad adelay: `ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -filter_complex "
tpad=start_duration=15:start_mode=clone;
adelay=15000:all=1
" out.mkv`

Comment: Thanks, it worked but when I combine it with another video the audio is lost for the second video.                      `ffmpeg -i outa1.mp4 -i out.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]scale2ref='oh*mdar':'if(lt(main_h,ih),ih,main_h)'[0s][1s]; [1s][0s]scale2ref='oh*mdar':'if(lt(main_h,ih),ih,main_h)'[1s][0s];[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]; [0s][1s]hstack,setsar=1" -map "[a]" -r 25 -ac 2 video.mp4 `

Comment: Try using `apad` filter ("pad audio with silence") instead of `adelay` filter ("delay one or more audio channels").

Comment: one step: `ffmpeg -i "1_orig.mp4" -i "2_orig.mp4" -filter_complex "
[0][1]scale2ref='oh*mdar':ih[v0][v1];
[v0]tpad=start_duration=15:start_mode=clone[v0];
[0]pan=mono|c0=FL+FR,adelay=15000:all=1[a0];
[1]pan=mono|c0=FL+FR[a1];
[v0][v1]hstack,setsar=1;
[a0][a1]amerge
" -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 20 -c:a aac -q:a 4 "/tmp/out.mp4" -y`

Comment: Many thanks for the help, but I get the following error `[Parsed_amerge_7 @ 0x559966fcd940] No channel layout for input 1
[Parsed_amerge_7 @ 0x559966fcd940] Input channel layouts overlap: output layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
[h264_nvenc @ 0x55996692f800] dl_fn->cuda_dl->cuInit(0) failed -> CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!`